# Steam Error - "There was an error retrieving trade offers"

Tags: steam

[image]

I've been getting this error constantly. Refreshing the page yields nothing, regardless if I do it through the Steam Browser or a internet browser (Chrome, Firefox, Netscape (lel), etc.)

I'd love to access my trade offers, but it seems I can't find any solution here.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Thanks for the error, but it also might be helpful to have some more info.  I'm not familiar with this service, but is it tied to an item/game?

Comment: Sounds like an error on steam's end. Have you contacted support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error often occurs, when the steam trading server is under heavy load. In example this happens right before important e-sports matches because players bet a lot of items on these games. In order to do this they have to trade via trade-offers with the betting systems.

The heavy server load makes your request (loading your trade offers) taking more time and after some seconds, if the load is not finished, a timeout occurs. This timeout results insuch errors.

The same problem also happens often to me, when i try to load my inventory with 3500+ items. It takes pretty long and if the server is too busy, I often get a timeout.